# Configuration file in PHP installation

Tags: php, linux, configuration, pear

I am using the following command to check for configuration file for PHP installation.

`$ php --ini`

But when I press enter, it is showing no output. It just comes to a new line without showing anything. Please help me in finding which configuration file is used by my PHP installation.

[image]

Basically, I am following the method shown in [this](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php) link for verifying my PEAR installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work - it works on my PHP 5.2.19/win32 installation -  and I don't know why it isn't working for you, but you can get the same info by either:

- Creating a php script which contains this line - `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` - and loading it in a browser. This will show you a lot of information about your PHP installation, including information about the INI file(s) in use.
- Running `php -i` from the command line - this will give you the same information as `phpinfo()` through the terminal. This may not work, if `php --ini` is not working. You could `grep` the output for instances of `ini`, e.g. `php --i | grep ini`

Something else that might be worth a try is redirecting the output of `php --ini` to a file, e.g. `php --ini > phpini.txt`.

Which PHP version are you running?

Comment: If you possibly can, upgrade - 5.1 is officially retired (5.2 is no longer actively developed) and is not guaranteed to support any given feature. If you run `php --help` does it list the `--ini` switch as being available?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, should output all your php info, configuration files included:

```
php -i |grep ".ini"
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally this should give you the configuration for your php. It looks like your php doesn't recognise the --ini parameter. Pass a php -h and look if --ini is supported by your installation.

What actually happens, your php is now waiting for input from you. Therefor it goes into the new line and waits for input.

What can also be, your system has set some default parameters for php by an alias. Call directly

```
/usr/bin/php --ini
```

maybe this helps. You can check if something is set by using

```
alias
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`php_ini_loaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php).

```
php -r "echo php_ini_loaded_file();"
```

Comment: I am getting output: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function php_ini_loaded_file() in Command line code on line 1`

Answer (score 0):

create a file

```
<?php
  echo phpinfo();
?>
```

save as phpinfo.php

run file in shell
    php phpinfo.php

or open in browser for nicer view.